# "You cannot register at this time" when trying to join a new Stack Exchange site

Tags: bug, error-message, sign-up

When I try to join a new site, I get the following error:

[image: You cannot register at this time. If you continue to find this error, contact us.]

> You cannot register at this time.
> If you continue to find this error, contact us.

I clicked the *Contact Us* link and filled out that form, but haven't received a response yet.

I also tried clicking the *Log In* button (the only other option available), but I get the same message.

Comment: Which Stack Exchange site did you experience this on? (Any/all of them, or a specific one?)

Comment: All of them as far as I know (I tried 4-5).

Comment: Have you tried changing browsers? Maybe it's something specific to your version of Firefox.

Comment: When I tried joining the site before logging in, it went through.  However, now that I am logged in again, the same problem is back.  On the other hand, this is a good workaround.  Just log out every time I wish to join a site -- it's not that often that I need to do it.

Comment: Likely the same bug reported today on MSO: ["You cannot register at this time" error when trying to register on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421631/8967612)

Comment: May not need to say this, but this bug has been around for months. thank you for making this post, as my attempt to contact was futile

Comment: @NotAPro there's no way to contact developers. One and only way to report bugs is submitting bug report here, and pray for the best. (Usually bugs that are non critical and not on the team radar to begin with will not be fixed.)

Comment: got a similar problem. hope that developers would see this post

Comment: I had this same problem multiple times today attempting to join arqade using chrome 113.0.5672.92. I tried safari (first one I tried) and it worked without issue.